What steps can be used to confirm if an AWS EKS cluster is not in use
While doing a cleanup of unused resources in our AWS environment, I discovered that an previous employee had setup an AWS EKS cluster which none of us were aware of. It looks like the cluster was never deployed or used in production. Is there any specific steps that I can take to confirm it is not being used, before deleting it? Unfortunately, AWS does not offer an option to stop it, only an option to delete it.
The EKS Kubernetes version is v1.21.
Things that I have already looked at:

There are no nodes in the compute tab.
There are no active pods in the Resources tab. All the sub sections of the Workload section are empty.
I don't see any activity in Cloudwatch for the cluster as well.


As there is no workloads it is safe to say that there is no running conatiners(application) in your cluster. You can check if there is any provisioned loadbalancers or volumes and then delete the cluster.
kubectl get svc,ingress,pv,pvc -A


If there are no nodes in the cluster, it's usually pretty safe to remove.
kubectl api-resources --verbs=list --namespaced -o name | xargs -n 1 kubectl get --ignore-not-found --show-kind

Will list everything in all namespaces (including volumes and custom resources), pretty handy if you want to take one final quick look. Perhaps there's a secret CronJob that runs once every month that wires salaries to all employees in your organization.
